# Filter access to certain views based on time?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a system whereby users can only access a certain page at a time which they have booked. Users who have not booked access to this time will not be able to access the page. Essentially the page will only be available to users once they have booked!

I am trying everything I can to do it see my files below.

models.py

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    daterequired = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    students = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        exclude = ['user', ]
        widgets = {
            'students': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Number of Students'}),
            'length': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Time needed in hours'}),
        }
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def choose(request):
    pod = Pod.objects.all()
    FMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    booking = Booking.objects.get(user=request.user)
    bookingtime = booking.daterequired
    currenttime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    tdelta = bookingtime - currenttime

    if str(tdelta) <= str(booking.length):
        print(tdelta)
        return render(request, 'choose.html', {'pod': pod, 'booking': booking})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<p>NO ACCESS</p>")
```

I am not sure how far off I am at the moment but would appreciate any help in the right direction.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booking.length is a CharField. You are trying to compare an int with a string. Booking.length should rather be an IntegerField.

If you can't modify this then you need to cast booking.length to an int to compare it to your time difference.

Also your timedifference is a timedelta. So you need to retrieve the number of seconds for instance (if booking.length is calculated in seconds). And you probably don't want the difference to be negative either (if ever it is possible to book in the future).

```
if 0 <= timedifference.seconds <= int(booking.length):
```

Note that you can also decide to store Booking.length as a DurationField in order to retrieve it as a timedelta rather than an int.

Comment: Thanks - I have changed Booking.length to be an Int field. I am having an issue when rendering the view however I am getting the message 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'daterequired' - any ideas why?

Comment: Booking.objects.filter(...) returns a queryset but you use it as if it were a model instance. You must either iterate over bookings if there may be several bookings matching your query. Or use 'get' instead of 'filter' if there can be only one booking matching your query

Comment: there can only be one

Comment: Then use Booking.objects.get(user=request.user)

Comment: I have updated my views.py I am now getting the error unconverted data remains: +00:00 - see above edit

Comment: You are missing the timezone part when parsing your date.

Comment: What do I put in for this?

Comment: Read the traceback and use your brain and documentation.

Comment: I have edited the view above I am extremely close! I am now receiving one minor error time data '2018-04-12 22:21:52+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

sorry to bother you but I have literally looked through every post and cannot figure out what is going wrong. thank you so much.

Comment: You are struggling to convert strings to datetimes. But... did you notice that you converted datetimes to strings to convert them back to datetimes? Why did you convert them to strings in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for this but Parser must be a string or character stream, not datetime?

Comment: Why are you using a parser ? What are you parsing ?

Comment: I have removed the parser and the string conversion error - see above. Still getting time data '2018-04-12 22:21:52+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'. When I remove .%f I get the message unconverted data remains: +00:00.

Comment: OK, now tell me what's that supposed to do : `time1 = datetime.strptime(str(bookingtime), FMT)`

Comment: I am over complicating! It is working now when I removed unnecessary functions. Now need to make sure it works for multiple users that have multiple bookings!

Comment: I am using the logic you suggested above however my booking.length is in hours. Is there an easy way to convert to seconds as you have suggested with my tdelta?

Comment: dividing seconds by 3600 gives hours

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much the system is now working if the user only has one booking! I need to now figure out how to make it work with a filter so that users can have multiple bookings.

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify this is to put the logic of comparing the current time against the booked time in a Booking method.

Then you can just test `booking.time_booked()` in any view where the check is needed.

It's not a complete answer so much as a recommendation, but I think you have a few questions bundled together here.